# Virtualbox VBoxManage show only results with sudo many info inside what I already tried in other post?

Tags: command-line, permissions, virtualbox, autostart

When I run this als normal user :

*VBoxManage list runningvms*

No results, also no error output, its compleet empty ....

When I run this with sudo :
*sudo VBoxManage list runningvms*

is see my VM is running
"homeassistant" {5e97e033-e726-41ec-a3aa-3f8e6b4bf448}

The normal user is

- a member of vboxusers
- remove this folder  rm -r ~/.config/VirtualBox
- set the folder permission with sudo chmod -R 752 ~/.config/VirtualBox

The problem is, I want to auto start the VM on a reboot, so I made a custom service

/etc/systemd.system/ha.service

*[Unit]
Description=vm1
After=network.target virtualbox.service
Before=runlevel2.target shutdown.target
[Service]
User=ovm
Group=ovm
Type=forking
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/hans/startha.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target*

/home.hans/startha.sh
*#! /bin/bash
sleep 40
VBoxManage startvm homeassistant  --type headless*

reload the config
*sudo systemctl daemon-reload*

enable the service
*systemctl enable ha.service*

reboot and after a couple of minutes check, but the user has no rights to start a VM
so how to handle  this ?

systemctl status ha

*ha.service - vm1
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ha.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-04-18 13:41:08 EDT; 5min ago
Process: 1119 ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/hans/startha.sh (code=exited, status=217/USER)
CPU: 1ms*

running Debian *uch uch*  with no GIU, the VMS is setup from terminal and is running fine when I start it with sudo

** edit **
when i run
*sudo ./startha.sh* from user hans the vm is starting normal ....

Comment: Change type in systemd file to "oneshot" and or change sudoers file to make command to use without sudo passwd. Or try runas command instead.

Answer (score 1):

it's solved..... for some reason the user has no (execute) rights on the .vbox file on \home....VirtualBox\ VMs

I run udo chmod 777 -R \home....VirtualBox\ VMs
and now can start the vm from a user and autostart is also working.